# Вертикальное выравнивание текста в блоке

Tags: html, css

На изображении изображены три блока, выровненные горизонтально:

1) изображение, 2) описание, 3) цена

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как правильно сверстать такой блок?
Проблема возникает в вертикальным выравниванием текста, т.е. прижатие его книзу.
Высоту для блоков нельзя ставить, т.к. будет адаптив

```css
ul{padding: 0;}
li {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
li> div {
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
}
li > div:nth-child(3) {
    float: right;
}

.img {
    font-size: 0;
}

.desc {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

h3 {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h3 a {
    color: #3a485b;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.desc-feature div {
    float: left;
}

.desc-feature div + div {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.price {
    position: relative;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #999;
}

.stock {
    padding-top: 63px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-17324886.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="desc">
      <div class="top">
        <h3><a href="#">Tesla S 75D</a></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="desc-feature">
        <div class="year">
          <span>Год: <strong>2017</strong></span>
        </div>
        <div class="milage">
          <span>Пробег: <strong>50 km</strong></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <strong>1000 $</strong>
      <div class="stock">
        <i></i>
        <span>В наличии</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: @alexander barakin, а где вопрос в виде картинки?

Comment: ваши слова также бесполезны без способа решения для базы знаний

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На скорую руку с флекс

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block1">
    <img src="http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/e1/pd/1078702682/1078702682_5216442493001_5216425414001-vs.jpg?pubId=1078702682" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="block2">
    <h3>Supercar 3000</h3>
    <span class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus, illo.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="block3">
    <span class="price">$1000</span>
    <span class="instok">В наличии</span>
  </div>
</div>


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
}
.wrap img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}
.block2 h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
.block2 {
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-around;
}
.block2 .desc {
  display: block;
}
.block3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-around;
  border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант, с помощью `flex`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clr:before,
.clr:after,
.row:before,
.row:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clr:after,
.row:after {
    clear: both;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: normal;
   color: #999;
}

span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.product__title {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

.product__title a {
  color: #3a485b;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.product__item {
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.product__img a,
.product__img img{
  display: block;
}

.product__desc {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.product__desc-left,
.product__desc-right{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
  .product__item {
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="product__list">
  <li class="product__item">
    <div class="product__img">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-17324886.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
  
    <div class="product__desc">
        <div class="product__desc-left">
            <h3 class="product__title"><a href="#">Tesla S 75D</a></h3>
          
            <div class="desc-feature">
              <span class="year">Год: <strong>2017</strong></span>
              <span class="milage">Пробег: <strong>50 km</strong></span>
            </div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="product__desc-right">          
          <div class="product__price">
            <strong>1000 $</strong>              
          </div>

          <div class="product__stock">
            <i></i>
            <span>В наличии</span>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
  </li>
</ul>
```